# Async counter that starts counting from 2

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, counter

I have to make an async counter that counts from 2 to 8. This is what I've done so far:
[image]

It counts from 0 to 8 and I don't know how to make it start counting from 2.

Comment: HINT: Your forgetting your binary 'weights'. Bit 0 =1, Bit 1 = 2, Bit 2 = 4, Bit 3 = 8.

Answer (score 1):

You are only using the Reset pins to clear the counter.

What you are really doing is presetting the counter to 0.

You can also use the Set pins instead of the Reset pin to preset any value you want the counter to start from, like 2.

(unused S and R inputs are of course are tied to the idle value)

Comment: yes, instead of the reset pin, if that is the bit you want to set as your "initial count"

Comment: Ok, I modified it a bit, now the output of the last FF is tied to the Set pin of the second FF and also it is tied to the Reset pin of the other FF-s. The problem is that the first time it starts counting from 0, only after the first time it starts from 2.

Comment: route the reset pin to the set pin of FF2.... keep in-mind polarity.  if reset is active-low, and set is active-high you will need an inverter to use reset line

Comment: They are both active-high

Comment: should work then

Comment: It doesn't, the first time it always starts from 0

Comment: did you remove the reset from FF2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78540/discussion-between-capnjj-and-eri).